# Change vertical distance between solutions in exsheets

Tags: exsheets

exsheets can be used to print out of solutions to a set of exercises. For example:

[image]

My question is, how do I reduce the vertical distance between solutions? This is what a series of questions and solutions look like (this code works) when using the exsheets package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\begin{document}
\begin{question}
   Answer this question
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
   This is the solution
 \end{solution}
\begin{question}
   Another question
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
   Another solution
\end{solution}
\printsolutions
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `skip-below` dimension for the solution environment.  (default= `+0.5\baselineskip`)

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}

 \SetupExSheets[solution]{skip-below = {-0.1\baselineskip}} % added  <<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    \begin{question}
        Answer this question
    \end{question}
    \begin{solution}
        This is the solution
    \end{solution}
    \begin{question}
        Another question
    \end{question}
    \begin{solution}
        Another solution
    \end{solution}
    \printsolutions
\end{document}
```

Comment: The solution given works. However, I also had a task list inside the solution, which added its own vertical space. Use after-skip=-10pt to remove that space as well, eg \settasks{after-skip=-10pt}